# matplotlib iterate subplot axis array through single list

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a simple/clean way to iterate an array of axis returned by subplots like

```
nrow = ncol = 2
a = []
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrow, ncols=ncol)
for i, row in enumerate(axs):
    for j, ax in enumerate(row):
        a.append(ax)

for i, ax in enumerate(a):
    ax.set_ylabel(str(i))
```

which even works for `nrow` or `ncol == 1`.

I tried list comprehension like:

```
[element for tupl in tupleOfTuples for element in tupl]
```

but that fails if `nrows` or `ncols == 1`

Comment: The solution which also works with a single axis is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649912/774575).

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The `ax` return value is a numpy array, which can be reshaped, I believe, without any copying of the data.  If you use the following, you'll get a linear array that you can iterate over cleanly.

```
nrow = 1; ncol = 2;
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrow, ncols=ncol)

for ax in axs.reshape(-1): 
  ax.set_ylabel(str(i))
```

This doesn't hold when ncols and nrows are both 1, since the return value is not an array; you could turn the return value into an array with one element for consistency, though it feels a bit like a cludge:

```
nrow = 1; ncol = 1;
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrow, ncols=nrow)
axs = np.array(axs)

for ax in axs.reshape(-1):
  ax.set_ylabel(str(i))
```

[reshape docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).
The argument `-1` causes reshape to infer dimensions of the output.

Comment: For `nrow=ncol=1` you can use `squeeze=0`.  `plt.subplots(nrows=nrow, ncols=nrow, squeeze=0)` always returns a 2 dimensional array for the axes, even if both are one.

Comment: This suggestion will not work because axs is not a numpy array in the case nrow=ncol=1. squeeze=0 works!

Answer (score 70):

The `fig` return value of `plt.subplots` has a list of all the axes. To iterate over all the subplots in a figure you can use:

```
nrow = 2
ncol = 2
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrow, ncol)
for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
    ax.set_ylabel(str(i))
```

This also works for `nrow == ncol == 1`.

Comment: so we don't need the `axs` then?

Comment: this is so simple and so useful!

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 23):

I am not sure when it was added, but there is now a `squeeze` keyword argument. This makes sure the result is always a 2D numpy array. Turning that into a 1D array is easy:

```
fig, ax2d = subplots(2, 2, squeeze=False)
axli = ax2d.flatten()
```

Works for any number of subplots, no trick for single ax, so a little easier than the accepted answer (perhaps `squeeze` didn't exist yet back then).

Comment: did you mean `ax2d.flatten()` in your second line? Otherwise it's unclear what `ax1d` is referencing.

Comment: @notlink Ow yeah that makes more sense

Answer (score 19):

You can use `numpy`'s `.flat` attribute on the `axes` object.

Here is an example

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3)
for ax in axes.flat:
    ## do something with instance of 'ax'
```

Comment: `.flat` is an attribute of the numpy array and has nothing to do with matplotlib.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for correcting my answer. I got confused.

Answer (score 11):

TLDR; axes.flat is the most pythonic way of iterating through axes

As others have pointed out, the return value of plt.subplots() is a numpy array of Axes objects, thus there are a ton of built-in numpy methods for flattening the array. Of those options **axes.flat** is the least verbose access method. Furthermore, axes.flatten() returns a *copy* of the array whereas axes.flat returns an iterator to the array. This means axes.flat will be more efficient in the long run.

Stealing @Sukjun-Kim's example:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3)
for ax in axes.flat:
    ## do something with instance of 'ax'
```

sources:
[axes.flat docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html)
[Matplotlib tutorial](https://youtu.be/6gdNUDs6QPc?t=2686)

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a good practice:**
For example, we need a set up four by four subplots so we can have them like below:

```
rows = 4; cols = 4;
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, figsize=(20, 16), squeeze=0, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axes = np.array(axes)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.reshape(-1)):
  ax.set_ylabel(f'Subplot: {i}')
```

*The output is beautiful and clear.*