# Best way to represent relation between two grouped bar plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, bar-chart

Say we have two datasets below:

```
data1 = {
         'A' : pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40], index = [1, 2, 3, 4]), 
         'B' : pd.Series([8, 15, 29, 42], index = [1, 2, 3, 4]),
         'C' : pd.Series([7, 13, 31, 45], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])
        }

data2 = {
         'A' : pd.Series([9, 18, 27, 38], index = [1, 2, 3, 4]), 
         'B' : pd.Series([11, 17, 28, 41], index = [1, 2, 3, 4]),
         'C' : pd.Series([12, 17, 29, 42], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])
        }
```

I can represent the `data1` using a grouped bar chart, where the x-axis is have ticks [1, 2, 3, 4]. Within each tick, I can have three sections 'A', 'B' and 'C' and I can form barchart with the values in the dataset. A generic example of a grouped bar chart is
[image: here].

I can also form a similar group bar chart for `data2`.

Is there a way that I can combine these two group charts in a single plot? Is there any other kind of chart that can be used to represent both `data1` and `data2` in a single plot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do a back to back barchart.. or whatever it's called, with some modification from the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863575/pandas-bar-plot-using-subplots) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
pd.DataFrame(data1).plot(kind="barh",ax=axes[0])
axes[1]= pd.DataFrame(data2).plot(kind="barh",ax=axes[1])
axes[0].invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The other option is to use a facet:

```
import seaborn as sns
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1).reset_index()
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2).reset_index()
df = pd.concat([data1,data2])
df['dataset'] = np.repeat(['1','2'],[4,4])

sns.catplot(data=df.melt(id_vars=["index","dataset"]),aspect=1,
            x="dataset",y="value",col="index",hue="variable",kind="bar")
```

[image]

Comment: That might work if `data1` and `data2` has a significant difference. For eg. in your graph, the top group looks exactly the same until I look very closely. Basically, it is difficult to see the comparison.

Comment: Ok so can you be clear about what you want to see or what you have tried to code. Seems like there is no clear answer to the question

Comment: Alright. So, I tried plotting a group bar chart for `data1` and then plot `data2` on top of it as a scatter plot. I use colour-coding and marker-styles to separate `A`, `B` and `C`'s dots. I thought it was an okay solution but I thought maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You can try with a facet..

Comment: That is also an interesting solution.